# How to add sid to a socket request?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-client

When connecting to sockets, many sockets of connection requests are sent and a sid is returned in each request

How after the first request to receive sid, send it in subsequent socket requests

here is my socket on the client:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

export const socket = io('http://localhost:3000', {
  autoConnect: false,
  reconnectionAttempts: 3,
  withCredentials: true,
})
```

after I do `socket.connect()` the request is sent
http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OhLPtYt
the request returns:
`97:0{"sid":"27GDQEg6qeB60PikAAAb","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}2:40`

but sid is not added to the following requests

How can I add sid parameters to all the following request to query params?